# I have a problem with adsterra ads, I added the code to my Blogger Blog and the ads does not show

Tags: javascript, html, themes, ads, blogger

this is the ad code :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
        'key' : 'dfb953ae8a73eec0b5f4d32f79c65b3a',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 60,
        'width' : 468,
        'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://paltryheadline.com/dfb953ae8a73eec0b5f4d32f79c65b3a/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
```

I tried to write the code in html-based version and it does not work, it show me that message :

```
Anonymous Proxy detected, click here.
```

and this is the code in html-based :

```html
<iframe src="//www.paltryheadline.com/watchnew?key=dfb953ae8a73eec0b5f4d32f79c65b3a" width="468" height="60" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

I also tried many different themes and I get the same problem

right now I am using seo plus theme v5 the free version

so if any one can help me solve this problem I will be grateful .

Comment: Where are you placing the script code? Into a new HTML/Javacript widget or into the template itself?

Comment: I place it into a new HTML/JavaScript widget

Comment: and actually it is the same problem when I place a social bar or a popunder ad into the template